# VBA Runtime Error 424 (Object Required) / Match cells between sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a main sheet with an x number of columns. I'm trying to find a match between the first cell in each column and another cell in a number of worksheets. Once the match is found, I'm trying to copy the entire column (excluding the matched value) and paste it onto the worksheet where the worksheet was found. I keep getting a Runtime error 424. The code I wrote is the following

```
Dim lc As Long
Dim cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim sh4 As Worksheet
Dim v As Long


Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
Set sh4 = Sheets(4)

lc = sh4.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For v = 1 To lc
Set cell1 = sh4.Cells(1, v)

    For Each Sheet In wbk.Worksheets
        If Sheet.Index > 5 Then
        Sheet.Select
        Set cell2 = Range("B1")

            If StrComp(CStr(cell1.Value), CStr(cell2.Value), vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
                  If cell1.Offset(0, 0).Value = cell2.Offset(0, 0).Value Then
                    sh1.Range(Cells(2, v), Cells(28, v)).Resize(1, 2).Copy
                    Sheet.Range("F2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                  End If
            End If
        End If

    Next Sheet
    Set cell1 = Nothing
    Set cell2 = Nothing
Next v
```

I feel like it's something simple that Im missing. Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In the code you showed us, you haven't defined `sh1` anywhere, so that's probably what's causing the error.

Comment: @djikay I'm sorry that was a typo on here it was supposed to be sh4. It still doesn't work

Comment: I'm getting a different runtime error (1004). I'll try reposting under a different title

Comment: You also need to qualify your `Cells` objects. I suspect you should add `sh4.` before them, e.g.: `sh4.Range(sh4.Cells(2, v), sh4.Cells(28, v)).Resize(1, 2).Copy`. If you don't do that, then they refer to whatever sheet is active/selected at the time. It's good practice to be specific about what sheet your various objects are referring to.

Comment: You haven't told us _on which line_ the error occurs, and the values of the variables referenced on that line when the error occurs.

Comment: Another thing: `cell1.Offset(0, 0).Value` is the same as `cell1.Value`, since you're offsetting by 0 rows and columns, i.e. you're not offsetting. Same for the `cell2` case.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things seemed wrong with your code. I went ahead and added some quick fixes to hopefully make it run fine. I, personally, HATE the Excel `.Paste` and `.PasteSpecial` functions (the hatred is mutual) so I always end up creating lists or using variables to copy stuff around.

Unfortunately I don't think the `.Resize` function does what you expect it to. By using it the way you do, you're only grabbing the first row and first two columns starting from the first cell of the range your resizing from.

Here's some code that should do the exact same thing as your code, minus the error messages! If you need some help understanding some of the changes I made or how to achieve your goals, don't hesitate to ask!

```
Dim lc As Long
Dim cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim sh4 As Worksheet, sh as Worksheet
Dim v As Long
Dim value1 As Variant, value2 As Variant

Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
Set sh4 = wbk.Sheets(4)

lc = sh4.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For v = 1 To lc
    Set cell1 = sh4.Cells(1, v)
    value1 = cell1.Value

    For Each sh In wbk.Worksheets
        If sh.Index > 5 Then
            sh.Select
            Set cell2 = sh.Range("B1")

            If StrComp(CStr(value1), CStr(value2), vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
                If value1 = value2 Then
                    sh.Range("F2") = sh4.Cells(2, v)
                    sh.Range("G2") = sh4.Cells(2, v + 1)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next sh

    Set cell1 = Nothing
    Set cell2 = Nothing

Next v
```

Comment: Awesome. I tried it, had no errors but it didn't work. Also, what if I wanted sh.Range("F2") to equal to column "v" from sh4 starting with row 2 to last row in that column? Thank you.